# How to see passed variable/parameters in GitLab CICD Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline triggered from the GitLab UI (CICD >> Pipelines >> Run Pipeline) by someone else and I want to know or audit the Used Variables/Parameters for the Completed Pipelines. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box as it would pose a security risk. If you need to be able to see specific variables for a job (and it is safe to do so for your use case) then you can echo those specific variables in your job scripts, which will ensure they are visible in the job logs. Alternatively, you could write them to a file and save that file as an artifact (which can also have an expiration).

Again - please do not this with secrets or sensitive variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be masking any secrets. In a job, add this into the script: `env` (assuming you are running GNU/Linux).